# HTML form sending to MySQL via PHP

Tags: php, html

I got a little problem. I am trying to send some data from my page to my database.

HTML Code:

```
[insert_php]
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); //I am using wordpress and I need php on page script.
    echo $current_user->ID; // here it shows "1" because I am admin.
[/insert_php]

<form action="http://mysitee.com/xxx.php" method="post">
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
    Nick: <input type="text" name="user_name">
    Server: <select name="server">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3" selected>3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="reward" value="123">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="[insert_php]echo "$current_user->ID";[/insert_php]">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And heres the PHP Code:

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('site.com', 'login', 'pass');
    mysql_select_db('mydb');

    // Check connection
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['user_id']);
    $user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['user_name']);
    $server = mysql_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['server']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
    $nagroda = mysql_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['reward']);

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO winners (user_id, user_name, server, email, reward)
    VALUES ('$user_id', '$user_name', '$server', '$email', '$nagroda')");

    if (!mysql_query($link)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error($link));
    }

    echo "1 record added";

    mysql_close($link);
?>
```

After all I should get user_id 1 in my database table but I am getting "0" and I am getting no varbiables in other columns. Also when I start this script I am just getting "Error:". Any ideas?

Comment: Your error handling is incorrect. Capture the result of the first call to `mysql_query()` in a variable and check to see if that is false. If so, then display `mysql_error()`.

Comment: You're using a `mysqli` based method `mysql_real_escape_string($link` get rid of the `$link,` or better yet, use `mysqli_*` exclusively.

Comment: Sorry guys. I am really newbie at PHP/HTML. Could you explain me a little more better what to change and where?

Comment: I believe I just did.

Comment: Yeah Fred. I am kinda nervous and didn't read it like I should. You were right. Now I got other problem. Actually I am getting all the data to my database but I am still getting echo "Error:". Why I am getting error if record has been added? Pretty weird.

Comment: What is the "exact" error message?

Comment: I just said it :) Hope you don't mind if I paste link to screenshot here. http://scr.hu/1htz/gr73f

Comment: It's this `$nagroda` there is nothing assigned to it. You might have meant to use `$reward`

Comment: You're running `mysql_query` twice. The first time with your query, and the second time with `$link`. The latter is failing - you're not checking the first call at all.

Comment: Nah Fred. Lets check PHP code once again.

$nagroda = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reward']);
php:
mysql_query("INSERT INTO winners (user_id, user_name, server, email, nagroda)
VALUES ('$user_id','$user_name', '$server', '$email', '$nagroda')");

and html: <input type="hidden" name="reward" value="123">

So as you can see my variable $nagroda is "reward" from HTML. Atleast I belive in it...

Comment: Yeah, I just changed it and it still gives me an error. It's working anyway, I am getting records in my table but I am just wondering why I am getting this error.

Comment: Consult my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23252935/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here. You were calling `mysql_query()` twice as Andrewsi stated, when using `mysql_query("INSERT...` and `if (!mysql_query($link))`

Plus, you're using a mysqli-based method `mysql_real_escape_string($link` get rid of the `$link,` or better yet, use `mysqli_*` exclusively.

Modified to read as `$query = mysql_query("INSERT...` then using the query variable
`if (!$query,$link)` instead.

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('site.com', 'login', 'pass');
    mysql_select_db('mydb');

    // Check connection
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_id']);
    $user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
    $server = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['server']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $nagroda = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reward']);

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO winners (user_id, user_name, server, email, reward)
    VALUES ('$user_id', '$user_name', '$server', '$email', '$nagroda')");

    if (!$query) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    echo "1 record added";

    mysql_close($link);
?>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

---

***Plus,***

Here are a few tutorials on (mysqli) prepared statements that you can study and try:

- [**Tutorial one**](http://webdevtuts.co.uk/simple-mysqli-tutorial/#more-41)
- [**Tutorial two**](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/PHP-5%3a-MySQLi-Prepared-Statements/41452)
- [**Tutorial three**](http://www.phpmysqlitutorials.com/2011/04/16/mysqli-whats-the-difference-between-standard-queries-and-prepared-statements/)

Here are a few tutorials on PDO:

- [**PDO tutorial one**](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)
- [**PDO tutorial two**](http://crewow.com/PHP-PDO-to-Connect-MySQL-Database.php)
- [**PDO tutorial three**](http://www.w3resource.com/php/pdo/php-pdo.php)

Comment: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home/script.php on line 19 "

Comment: Give me a sec. I'll check it. @user3565273

Comment: I changed it to `if (!$query)` try it now @user3565273 and `mysql_error($link)` to `mysql_error()`

Comment: Working, thanks you Fred ;) One more question if you could. How can I make this echo on same page? I don't want people to get redirected to another page, just I want that notify "1 record added" at same page when they click "submit". Any ideas or links?:)

Comment: You're welcome. In order for it to echo on the same page, you would need to have your form on the same page, and using `action=""` instead of `action="handler.php"` for example @user3565273

Comment: You know what to do now right? (wink). Click the little white checkmark till it turns green to accept my answer. That lets SO know that a solution was found. @user3565273

Comment: Sorry, I am new here. I really know how much reputation matters here. I just forgot about it. Thanks you for help :) Hope you don't mind if I create more threads when I'll  need help. Cya guys :)

Comment: You're welcome, was glad to have helped. We're always happy to help for any future problems you may encounter, cheers. @user3565273 That's what we're here for ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Its -

```
mysql_real_escape_string(string, connection)
```

and you have done the opposite of it. Fix as below -

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_id'], $link)
```

**SUGGESTION:** Don't use mysql_* statements as they are deprecated in recent PHP versions. Learn mysqli prepared or PDO.

Comment: `, $link` is not really needed. (link_identifier)

    The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated. As per the manual http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, it is optional. Still showing what mistake OP has done in his code.

Comment: True, yet as I stated in a [`comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252550/html-form-sending-to-mysql-via-php#comment35580770_23252550) however it seems like the OP is faced with another problem, so get ready ;-)

Comment: Still got one problem (sorry for doubling). Even if my whole record has been added I am still getting echo with "error:". Any ideas why when I actually got filled my whole record in my database?

Comment: @Fred-ii- `Error` means, OP is getting some error here `if (!mysql_query($link)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error($link));
    }`

Answer (score 0):

```
There is a little modification in the code. I think it ll help
    <?php
        $link = mysql_connect('site.com', 'login', 'pass');
        mysql_select_db('mydb');

        // Check connection
        if (!$link) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['user_id']);
        $user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['user_name']);
        $server = mysql_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['server']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
        $reward = mysql_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['reward']);

        $sql="INSERT INTO winners (user_id, user_name, server, email, reward)
        VALUES ('$user_id', '$user_name', '$server', '$email', '$nagroda')";

        if (!mysql_query($sql,$link)) {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error($link));
        }

        echo "1 record added";

        mysql_close($link);
    ?>
```